# JButton method I cannot find

Tags: java, computer-science

I'm working on a TicTacToe game at the moment as a personal project and so far I know I'm almost complete with the game except for the part where I have to check if the x or o's are equal and in a line. Here's my code below here. My problem is in the connected method, it compiles and run's, but when I tried to add the middle horizontal row after just only one JButton was pressed it said the person won which should not be the case. I think I need a method that is named isDisabled(), instead of isEnabled for the JButton, but for some reason I don't think there is such a method in the java library. I know for sure if I had isDisabled() it would work for sure

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/**
 * Created by Usman on 5/17/2016.
 */
public class TicTacToeGUI extends JPanel {

    boolean turn = true;
    JButton[] board;

    public TicTacToeGUI() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

        board = new JButton[9];
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            board[i] = new JButton("");
            board[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 60));
            board[i].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
            int finalI = i;
            board[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    if(board[finalI].isEnabled()){
                        if(turn){
                            board[finalI].setText("X");
                            turn = !turn;
                        }
                        else{
                            board[finalI].setText("O");
                            turn = true;
                        }
                        board[finalI].setEnabled(false);
                    }
                    Connected();
                }
            });
            add(board[i]);
        }
    }
    public void Connected(){
        int count =0;
        //Horizontal top row
        if((board[0].isEnabled() == board[1].isEnabled()) && (board[1].isEnabled() == board[2].isEnabled())){
            System.out.println(count++);
            for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
                board[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        TicTacToeGUI game = new TicTacToeGUI();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tic Tac Toe");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(game);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `isDisabled` would just be the negation of `isEnabled`, in other words `!isEnabled()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `(!whatever.isEnabled())`

The character '!' is similar to a NOT in Java. So it will behave like isDiabled()